# Photoshop - Background color for multiple shape objects on multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have multiple layers with rectangle shapes on each, i want to apply same color to every shape at once.

Can anyone share a tip?

Thanks,

Comment: no..no smart objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method 1 for cs6

1)Select each shape layer, then select a shape tool (Rectangle tool, ellipse tool, etc.) In the Options bar at the top, there is a dropdown for fill and stroke. If you have each shape layer selected, change the fill and it will change all of them. If you're using the eyedropper from there, you won't see the colors change until you click "OK".

Method 2

1)  You can change "colour overlay" in "blending options" of a shape, than "copy     layer style" of the shape, select shapes you need to change and "paste layer style"

2)  Select shapes and make a "smart object". Now you can work with it like you work with a simple layer. You can edit smart object by choosing "edit content" menu